# What are the implications of turning on the plugins attribute of an Electron webview?

Tags: electron, chromium, chrome-plugins

Can somebody explain what the `plugins` attribute of the `Webview` tag actually does? What plugins does it allow? Only those that I, the developer, add?

```
<webview src="example.com" plugins></webview>
```

The [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#plugins) just say:

> When this attribute is present the guest page in webview will be able to use browser plugins.

My Electron app needs to show PDFs, which I can only do by setting this attribute, but I want to make sure that there aren't other adverse effects/implications of turning this on.

I don't want some random plugins to be running that I don't have control of (my understanding is that extensions are installed by users, but plugins are "installed" by the Chrome team, and we can't control what runs [barring Flash and the PDF Viewer]).

Running `navigator.plugins` in the console window of my Electron app shows an array of one element with name `Chromium PDF Viewer`, which is reasurring, but is there a chance that another plugin will get in that array, or would I have to be the one who adds that plugin?

---

Update: [As of Chrome 57](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615738) (Electron 2 uses Chrome 61), the only plugins that we can control are the PDF Viewer (which Electron apparently ships with) and [Flash](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-pepper-flash-plugin).

If we want to use the built-in PDF Viewer, we have no choice but to specify the `plugins` attribute and trust Chrome's other plugins.

To answer my question above:

> Is there a chance that another plugin will get in that array, or would I have to be the one who adds that plugin?

It would appear that I would have to be the one that adds it, but again, that's not stopping other Chrome plugins from running.